# Convert named list to vector with values only

Tags: r, list

I have a list of named values:

```
myList <- list('A' = 1, 'B' = 2, 'C' = 3)
```

I want a vector with the value `1:3`

I can't figure out how to extract the values without defining a function. Is there a simpler way that I'm unaware of?

```
library(plyr)
myvector <- laply(myList, function(x) x)
```

Is there something akin to `myList$Values` to strip the names and return it as a vector?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Use `unlist` with `use.names = FALSE` argument.

```
unlist(myList, use.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: Note, that `unlist` will silently work even if elements of `myList` are of `length()!=1`: `unlist(list(1, 2, 3:4)) == c(1, 2, 3, 4)`. This is different from the OP `plyr` solution and from simply using `as.integer(myList)` and might not be what you want/expect.

Answer (score 21):

`purrr::flatten_*()` is also a good option. the `flatten_*` functions add thin sanity checks and ensure type safety.

```
myList <- list('A'=1, 'B'=2, 'C'=3)

purrr::flatten_dbl(myList)
## [1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: Both flatten() and unlist() drop NULL elements by default. Any way to preserve these?

Answer (score 8):

This can be done by using `unlist` before `as.vector`.
The result is the same as using the parameter `use.names=FALSE`.

```
as.vector(unlist(myList))
```

Comment: What is the advantage of calling two functions instead of one?