# Read multiple .txt files into R Vector as Individual Elements

Tags: r, text, nlp

I have a folder on my desktop named "project". Inside this folder are multiple .txt files (e.g. 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, etc.). Does anyone know of a solution that would enable me to have a vector where each element in the vector corresponds to the contents of the file?

For example, if 1.txt contains "You like apples", 2.txt contains "I like pears", and 3.txt contains "Cats like fish"..... I would like the result to be a vector of length 3 where each element contains the entirety of the text in the .txt file. Essentially (("I like apples"),("You like pears"),("Cats like fish")).

My current partial-solution can read one text file in the way I would like, but how can I do this for every .txt file in a dir and store it accordingly?

```
fileName <- '/Users/myname/Desktop/1.txt'
text <- readChar(fileName, file.info(fileName)$size)
```

Many thanks! I'm competing in a hackathon and need this to create a tf-idf implementation and each element in the vector will be a document.

Answer (score 5):

Try: (if all the files are in the working directory)

```
files <- list.files(pattern="^\\d+\\.txt")
files
#[1] "1.txt" "2.txt" "3.txt"

unname(sapply(files, readLines))
#[1] "You like apples" "I like pears"    "Cats like fish"
```

If you have files in a different directory

```
fileDir <- "/home/akrunHome/TestN"
files <- list.files(fileDir, pattern="^\\d+\\.txt")
files1 <- paste(fileDir, files, sep="/") 
unname(sapply(files1, readLines))
#[1] "You like apples" "I like pears"    "Cats like fish"
```

Based on @Roman Luštrik's comments, you could do:

```
 paste(unname(sapply(files1, readLines)), collapse=", ")
 #[1] "You like apples, I like pears, Cats like fish"
```

Or perhaps you need

```
  paste(paste0("'", unname(sapply(files1, readLines)),"'"), collapse=", ")
 #[1] "'You like apples', 'I like pears', 'Cats like fish'"
```

Comment: First off, thank you for the help. Secondarily, we're almost there but the format I need is to have each string of characters separated by commas. Effectively: #[1] "You like apples", "I like pears", "Cats like fish". Is this an easy fix for you?

Comment: @uspowpow collapse the string using `paste` and its argument `collapse`. Whatever character you provide will be inserted between strings.

Answer (score 0):

If the files contain multiple lines, we get a list using `unname` from @akrun 's answer.  `unlist` can then [convert the list to a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094774/better-way-to-convert-list-to-vector):

```
myList <- unname(sapply(filesMultipleLines, readLines))
myVector <- unlist(myList, use.names=FALSE)
```