# Looking for a function to return list components as a vector

Tags: r

I have the following list:

```
myList <- list(
  parameter_a = "Price", parameter_b = "Quantity",
  parameter_c = "Name"
)
```

and I would like a function to get me the following vector:

```
c("Price", "Quantity", "Name")
```

I found this combination: `unlist(unname(myList))` which makes exactly what I need.

But is there a single function for that (other than `unlist()`)?

The answer of  [Better way to convert list to vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094774/better-way-to-convert-list-to-vector) describes the function `unlist()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`as.character` works here

```
as.character(myList)
#[1] "Price"    "Quantity" "Name"
```

---

A more general approach would be `as.vector` with mode as "character"

```
as.vector(myList, mode = "character")
#[1] "Price"    "Quantity" "Name"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap both in a custom function:

```
my_unlist <- function(x) unlist(unname(x))

my_unlist(myList)

#[1] "Price"    "Quantity" "Name"
```

Just in case `as.character` should fail.